# Как в цикле foreach отключить условие

Tags: c#, foreach

Есть код к примеру:

```
   foreach (DataRow row1 in ds.Tables[2].Rows)
   {
     if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(row1["clID"].ToString()))
     {
       // какое то действие  
       dict.Add("{Note}", "Примечание");
       break;
     }
     if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(row1["clID"].ToString()))
     {
       // другое действие  
       dict.Add("{Note}", "Заметка");
       break;
     }
   }
```

Результат процедуры:

```
| ID | clID |            
+----+------+            
| 1  | 1444 |            
| 2  | 1456 |            
| 3  | null |
| 4  | null |
```

Как отменить 2-й `if`, если 1-й `if` выполняется.
Проблема в том что после выполнение первой условии, переходит на второй, и выводить ошибку
Нужно если в таблице хоть один  clID нулевой то  тогда выполнялась 1-й if,
если в таблице все clID не `null` то второе условие

Comment: `else if` .......

Comment: У вас второй if и так уже "отменен" оператором `break;`

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, да, и первый  if тоже выполняется и выходило исключение

Comment: У вас ошибка в другом месте, и к "отключению условия" она не имеет никакого отношения.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, в данном случаи первый if  выполняется когда  третьи раз заходим в массив и отменяем. Потом была проблема второй if  тоже удовлетворял наше условие и тоже выполнялся и выходило исключение. А мне нужно если в таблице хоть один clID нулевой то тогда выполнялась 1-й if и все

Answer (score 2, accepted):

так как условия здесь противоположные. можно заменить два `if`, на конструкцию `if-else`

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(row1["clID"].ToString()))
{
   // какое то действие  
   dict.Add("{Note}", "Примечание");
   break;
} else {
   // другое действие  
   dict.Add("{Note}", "Заметка");
   break;
}
```

Возможно стоит подумать об использовании функции [`Convert.ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.convert.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) вместо вызова метода `ToString`. Если *row1["clID"]* - уже `null`, то при использовании первой функции не будет ошибки, а при использовании второй - будет исключение.

---

**Обновление под вопрос:** в данном случае условие нужно проверять **до** выполнения действий, например с помощью linq: [мeтод Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb337697(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
if(ds.Tables[2].Rows.AsEnumerable().Any(dr=>String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(row1["clID"])))){
    foreach (DataRow row1 in ds.Tables[2].Rows)
    {
        // какое то действие  
        dict.Add("{Note}", "Примечание");
    }
}else{
    foreach (DataRow row1 in ds.Tables[2].Rows)
    {
        // другое действие  
        dict.Add("{Note}", "Заметка");
    }
}
```

Comment: в данном случае вторая условия тоже выполняется, то есть нужно без else if(....)

Comment: @Zhandos, в моем ответе **нет** `else if` как нет и второго условия

Comment: @Zhandos, обновил ответ

Comment: как можно это реализовать через ado.net

Comment: здесь   первый if не выполняется так как у id=1 clID не нулл, а мне нужно чтобы через foreach цикл проверял все строчки, и выполнялся первый if и не заходил на вторую

Answer (score 0):

можете создать переменную типа boolean как флаг выполнения, в начали итерации флаг = false, если условие выполнилось - true, и читаете этот флаг, где нужно. В конце тела цикла сбрасываете флаг в false.

Answer (score -1):

```
   Boolean isCond = false;
   foreach (DataRow row1 in ds.Tables[2].Rows)
   {
     if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(row1["clID"].ToString()))
     {
       // какое то действие  
       dict.Add("{Note}", "Примечание");
       isCond = true;
       break;
     }
     if (!isCond)
     {
        foreach (DataRow row1 in ds.Tables[2].Rows)
        {
           if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(row1["clID"].ToString()))
           {
             // другое действие  
             dict.Add("{Note}", "Заметка");
             break;
           }
      }
   }
```